# List all types registered with a Castle Windsor container instance

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

What's the easiest way of programatically listing registered types in Castle Windsor?

Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `IKernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(object))`:

```
IWindsorContainer container = ...

foreach (var handler in container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(object))) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", 
       handler.ComponentModel.Service, 
       handler.ComponentModel.Implementation);
}
```

Comment: is there any solution, if want to visualize all the registered service and component, without using the name of service or component,

such as we register them , FromAssembly() or something like that is available for check the available services ??

Answer (score 0):

Further to Mauricio's excellent answer, if `handler.ComponentModel.Service` cannot be found use this instead:

```
IWindsorContainer container = ...

foreach (var handler in container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(object))) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", 
       String.Join(",", handler.ComponentModel.Services), 
       handler.ComponentModel.Implementation);
}
```