# How do I get all the key for the components that are currently register in Castle Windsor?

Tags: castle-windsor, fluent-interface

The main question is in the title but here is the background.

Since I pick the lazy way to register my components

```
        container.Register(
            AllTypes.Pick().FromAssembly(
typeof (MyModelBinder).Assembly).WithService.FirstInterface()
           );
```

Now when I try

```
  container.AddComponent<CompositionBinder, CompositionBinder>();
```

Windsor told me there is already a component with the same keys

But if I comment out that line Windsors fail to resolve for CompositionBinder
Now if I do

```
    container.AddComponent<CompositionBinder, CompositionBinder>
("CompositionBinder");
```

Then it work. So I would like to peek under to engine to get an idea of what kind of Components and Keys that got register to my container.

How do I get all the key for the components that are currently register in Castle Windsor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550190/list-all-types-registered-with-a-castle-windsor-container-instance). ComponentModel has a Name property which is the component key.

Comment: Thank you. Glad that somebody know this stuff so well.