# How can i get all registered services in Castle.Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor

Is there any way to get all registered service type and implementation type in windsor container

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550190/list-all-types-registered-with-a-castle-windsor-container-instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

they don't map one to one, but you can get that by `container.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(object));`