# Castle not resolving all registered components

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have the following classes.

```
public interface ICampaignDal : ICrudDal<Campaign>
{
}
public class CampaignDal : BaseDal<Campaign>, ICampaignDal
{
}

public interface IPixelDal : ICrudDal<Pixel>
{
}
public class PixelDal : BaseDal<Pixel>, IPixelDal
{
}


public interface ICrudDal<T> where T : BaseEntity, new()
{
}
```

this is how I register them:

```
Container.Register(
     Types.FromAssembly(typeof (ICrudDal<>).Assembly)
             .BasedOn(typeof (ICrudDal<>)).WithServiceAllInterfaces());
```

When I resolve this, it works fine:

```
Container.Resolve<ICampaignDal>();
```

but this:

```
Container.Resolve<IPixelDal>();
```

will generate an error:

`"Type DataAccessLayer.IPixelDal is abstract.\r\n As such, it is not possible to instansiate it as implementation of service 'DataAccessLayer.IPixelDal'. Did you forget to proxy it?"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I inspected the container configuration using the following code (inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1550903/390819)):

```
foreach (var handler in c.Kernel.GetAssignableHandlers(typeof(object)))
    Console.WriteLine("{0} implemented by: {1}",
        String.Join(",", handler.ComponentModel.Services) ,
        handler.ComponentModel.Implementation);
```

The output of the above code is:

```
ConsoleApp.ICampaignDal,ConsoleApp.ICrudDal`1[ConsoleApp.Campaign] implemented by: ConsoleApp.CampaignDal
ConsoleApp.ICampaignDal,ConsoleApp.ICrudDal`1[ConsoleApp.Campaign] implemented by: ConsoleApp.ICampaignDal
ConsoleApp.ICrudDal`1[T] implemented by: ConsoleApp.ICrudDal`1[T]
ConsoleApp.ICrudDal`1[ConsoleApp.Pixel],ConsoleApp.IPixelDal implemented by: ConsoleApp.IPixelDal
ConsoleApp.ICrudDal`1[ConsoleApp.Pixel],ConsoleApp.IPixelDal implemented by: ConsoleApp.PixelDal
```

As you can see, there are two registrations for `IPixelDal` (last two lines). The default registration (the first of the two) says that `IPixelDal` is implemented by itself. Considering that this is an abstract type (interface), it is not possible to instantiate it, fact which is confirmed by the error message you get.

I made a simple adjustment to your code and it works OK:

```
Container.Register(
        Types.FromAssembly(typeof(ICrudDal<>).Assembly)
                .BasedOn(typeof(ICrudDal<>))
                .Unless(t => t.IsAbstract)
                .WithServiceAllInterfaces());
```

The `.Unless(t => t.IsAbstract)` line instructs the container to only auto-register concrete types.

*Disclaimer: I'm not a Castle Windsor user, so I'm not sure if this is a idiomatic solution. But it certainly works if you need a quick fix.*

Comment: Thank you, but why isnt this happened to the other types, it is all same same. thanks

Comment: @SexyMF You're right; it's weird. I have no idea why Castle would register an interface to itself.

Comment: @SexyMF and why it would treat `ICampaignDal` and `IPixelDal` differently in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Classes.` not `Types.` to just pick up concrete classes

Comment: He's correct. Using Classes you don't need 
.Unless(t => t.IsAbstract)